# How can I assign instance of a class from an array to a class initializer in java?

Tags: java, arrays, class

In a Android application I am making I have an array of instances of a certain class I made, and later in the program I need to use the getter and setter methods from that class on an instance of the class from the array. Do I need to assign the instance of the class from the array to a new class initializer? Here is some code to clear this up:

**Class**

```
public class ProfileInformation {

  private String console;
  private String gamertag;

  public String getConsole() {
    return console;
  }

  public void setConsole(String console) {
    this.console = console;
  }

  public String getGamertag() {
    return gamertag;
  }

  public void setGamertag(String gamertag) {
    this.gamertag = gamertag;
  }
}
```

**Array**

```
ArrayList<ProfileInformation> ProfTags = new ArrayList<>();
```

Some instances of ProfileInformation are then added to arraylist, and then I get one of the instances from the arraylist and try to use getGamertag() to set it to a string:

```
ProfileInformation profNew = ProfTags.get(ProfTags.size()-1);
String example = profNew.getGamertag();
```

The problem is example will equal null. Why is this?

Comment: Show us how you adding the stuff?

Comment: Also, this isn't android specific

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but are you actually setting the "gamertag" value?

Answer (score 0):

First, an Arraylist is a List, try not to confuse that with actual arrays.

> Do I need to assign the instance of the class from the array to a new class initializer?

You don't need to get an element out of the Arraylist, no. You can chain many methods together

```
String example = ProfTags.get(ProfTags.size()-1).getGamertag();
```

> example will equal null. Why is this?

For the same reason any object is null... You never set it equal to anything else

Answer (score 0):

This code runs on my laptop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ArrayList<ProfileInformation> ProfTags = new ArrayList<>();

  element = new ProfileInformation();
  element.setGamertag("Actual Gamer tag value");

  ProfTags.add(element);

  ProfileInformation profNew = ProfTags.get(ProfTags.size()-1);
  String example = profNew.getGamertag();
}
```

Output is:

`Actual Gamer tag value`

I guess you didn't call **setGamertag(String)**.